# For at least one point $x_0$ prove that $f''(x_0) = 0$

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

Here is the task:

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that is twice differentiable everywhere.

The function $f(x)$ intersects with the line $y = a + bx$ at least 3 times.

I have to show that there is at least 1 point $x_0$ such that $f''(x_0) = 0$.

It was suggested that to solve this one would check for all solutions where $f'(x) = b$. I have tried using the mean value theorem and inserting values such that the equation holds, but the answers i get doesn't really lead to anything.

How should i go about proving this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  the MVT tells us there's a solution to $f'(x)=b$ between any two intersections.  Thus we have at least two such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to find at least two points where $f' = c$ for some constant, and use Rolle's theorem to conclude the existence of $x_0$.

Since $f$ intersects $a + bx$ at least $3$ times, there exists $x_1< x_2< x_3$ such that $f(x_1) = a + bx_1, f(x_2) = a + bx_2,f(x_3) = a + bx_3$. By the mean value theorem, there exists $\xi_1,\xi_2$ such that
$$ b = \frac{f(x_2) - f(x_1)}{x_2 - x_1} = f'(\xi_1), b = \frac{f(x_3) - f(x_2)}{x_3 - x_2} = f'(\xi_2)
$$
At $\xi_1,\xi_2$, $f' = b$. By Rolle's theorem, there exists $\xi_1 < x_0 < \xi_2$ such that $f''(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: How does the mean value theorem tell you that there exist an $\xi_1$ and $\xi_2$?

Comment: @VictorVH Sorry it was a typo. It is fixed.

Comment: Henry could you explain that last line about Rolle's theorem a little further?
I read the section on wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem about the generalization to higher derivatives, but I can't quite make sense of it.

Comment: @VictorVH Here we are applying Rolle's theorem to $f'$ instead of $f$ using the fact that $f' = b$ at two different points.

Comment: Thanks Henry! I can see it now, I didn't realize it could be used that way, but of course $f'$ is also just a function.